# center anchor tag in grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to center a `<a>` tag that has a background image, inside a grid. But its always to the left of the grid.

[what the `<a>` is doing in the grid vs what I want it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM6vs.png)

@media query - I'm stacking the image  tag, on top of each other instead of side-by-side when the screen size is smaller.

```css
  main {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title title title" "classa classb classc";
}

.photoa {
  grid-area: classa;
  width: 175px;
  background: url(images/classa.png) no-repeat 0;
  opacity: .6;
}

.photob {
  grid-area: classb;
  width: 175px;
  background: url(images/classb.png) no-repeat 0;
  opacity: .6;
}

.photoc {
  grid-area: classc;
  width: 175px;
  background: url(images/classc.png) no-repeat 0;
  opacity: .6;
}

@media (max-width: 770px) {
  main {
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "title" "classa" "classb" "classc";
  }
```

```html
<main>
  <h3 class="title">Click image below</h3>
  <a href="classa.html" class="photoa"></a>
  <a href="classb.html" class="photob"></a>
  <a href="classc.html" class="photoc"></a>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Centering the tag is a matter of `margin: 0 auto`

Centering the background image is a matter of setting the `background-position: center`

I also added a border to the anchors tags for better visibility to see what's going on.

I wasn't seeing anything in the snippet window so I modified your media query.

```css
  main {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title title title" "classa classb classc";
}

a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.photoa {
  grid-area: classa;
  width: 175px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/40/40) no-repeat 0;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: .6;
}

.photob {
  grid-area: classb;
  width: 175px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/40/40) no-repeat 0;
  opacity: .6;
}

.photoc {
  grid-area: classc;
  width: 175px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/40/40) no-repeat 0;
  opacity: .6;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  main {
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "title" "classa" "classb" "classc";
  }
```

```html
<main>
  <h3 class="title">Click image below</h3>
  <a href="classa.html" class="photoa"></a>
  <a href="classb.html" class="photob"></a>
  <a href="classc.html" class="photoc"></a>
</main>
```